# Showing that the difference of these 2 meromorphic functions are bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, meromorphic-functions

I have the functions $g(z)=\frac{\pi^2}{sin^2(\pi z)}$ and $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$. I need to show that the function $f-g$ is bounded and holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

I know that both $f,g$ are holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$ with poles at $\mathbb{Z}$, and that their Laurent series at $z=0$ both have principal part $\frac{1}{z^2}$.  I am also given that they satisfy properties $f(z+1)=f(z)$, and $f(x+iy)\rightarrow0$ for $|y|\rightarrow\infty$. (Same applies for $g$).

If I could show that $f-g$ is bounded, then by Riemann extension the poles $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ would be removable singularities. Hence $f-g$ would extend to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$.

But I am struggling with the boundedness part. Since $g$ itself is not bounded and by writing out $g-f$ nothing seems to simplify/suggest that it is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Both are bounded when $z$ is not too close to an integer.

Looking around zero, which is enough,
$f(z)
=1/z^2+$ something bounded by comparison with
$\zeta(2)$
and
$\sin^2(\pi z)
= (\pi z)^2+O(z^4)$
so

$\dfrac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}
=\dfrac{\pi^2}{ (\pi z)^2+O(z^4)}
=\dfrac1{z^2(1+O(z^2))}
=\dfrac1{z^2}(1+O(z^2))
=1/z^2+O(1)
$

so their difference is bounded.

---

Adding more detail.

If $|z| < c$ 
where $c$ is small
($c < \frac12$, in particular) then

$\begin{array}\\
|f(z)-\dfrac1{z^2}|
&=|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}|\\
&\le 2|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-c)^2}|\\
&= 2|\frac1{(1-c)^2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-c)^2}|\\
&\le 2|\frac1{(1-c)^2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}|
\qquad ((n-c)^2 > n(n-1) \text{ for } c < \frac12)\ (*)\\
&\le 2|\frac1{(1-c)^2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac1{n})|\\
&\le 2|\frac1{(1-c)^2}+1|\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f(z)-\dfrac1{z^2}$
is bounded for small $z$.

$(*)\ (n-c)^2 > n(n-1)
\iff n^2-2nc+c^2 > n^2-n
\iff n(1-2c)+c^2 > 0
$

To show
$\dfrac1{1+O(z^2)}
=1+O(z^2)
$,
$\dfrac1{1+cz^2}-1
=\dfrac{-cz^2}{1+cz^2}
$
so
$|\dfrac1{1+cz^2}-1|
=|\dfrac{-cz^2}{1+cz^2}|
\lt 2c|z^2|
$
if
$|cz^2| < \frac12$
or
$|z| < \sqrt{\frac1{2c}}
$
so
$\dfrac1{1+O(z^2)}
=1+O(z^2)
$
as
$z \to 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by (2)? Also, how did you get $\frac{1}{1+O(z^2)} = 1+O(z^2)$? I am guessing this is due to geometric series, right? If so I think I understand. Lastly, how does this imply that their difference is bounded - isn't $O(1)$ just a polynomial, hence not bounded?

Comment: I added additional explanations. Also, $O(1)$ means a bounded expression.